# Chrome Packaged App: Retrieving FileEntry in Dart from command line (LaunchData) parameter

Tags: file, command-line, dart, google-chrome-app

Similarly to another post on this topic, I've been attempting to run my app from the command line with the file path of a local XML file so that my `main.dart` can parse this file in order to extract information relevant to program operation from it. I've been stumped as to how to appropriately access the `FileEntry` reference included in `launchData` -- the parameter for the `onLaunched` event.

Here's what I currently have:

**manifest.json**:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "fileSystem",
    "*://*/*"
],

"file_handlers" : {
    "any" : {
        "types" : [ "*" ]
    }
},
...
```

**background.js**:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {

  chrome.app.window.create(

  'htmlFile.html',

  {...},

  function(createdWindow) {
    createdWindow.contentWindow.launchData = launchData;
  });
});
```

At this point, I can't access `launchData` from `main.dart` because trying to do

```
  FileEntry entry =  (chrome.app.window.current().contentWindow.launchData as chrome.LaunchData).items.elementAt(0).entry;
```

to get the `FileEntry` results in an error for accessing `launchData`. I'm really confused about how I'm supposed to access the `FileEntry` that I want from my Dart code as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with this as my solution:

**manifest.json**:

```
...
"file_handlers": {
  "any": {
    "extensions": [
      "xml"
    ]
  }
}, 
...
```

**background.js**:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {

  chrome.app.window.create(
    'htmlSource.html',

  {
    id: 'mainWindow',
    state: "fullscreen"
  },

  function(createdWindow) {

    if(launchData.items !== undefined) {
      launchData.items[0].entry.file(

        function(result) {

          var reader = new FileReader();
          var XML;

          reader.onloadend = function(){
            XML = reader.result;
            chrome.storage.local.set({'XML': XML});
          };

          reader.readAsText(result);

        },

        function(){
          console.log("Error reading XML file");
        }

      );
    } else {
      console.log("No file was detected.");
    }
  });
});
```

The dart code to retrieve the XML was simply:

```
String text = (await chrome.storage.local.get('XML'))['XML'];
```